# Webpack process files(images) from two different directories

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have my webpack that current processes and optimizes my images from

`Directory A  (to)-> build/A`

I have another directory let's say

`Directory B and I need it to go to build/B`

How would I integrate the second flow?

Comment: How about including some config that shows what loaders you are using or describing your strategy of processing and optimizing your images?

Comment: I am not even sure were begin with the second flow

Comment: When you say process and optimize images, what do you mean? Do you mean just importing them into a file as a url? Is there some other processing that webpack is doing?

Comment: I have to directories in my project one is public/ that has all the images we can use with our cms and we have another directory in the src/images that has all the image resources --- bough need to be optimized during build and  distributed into different directories i.e build/images and build/public